# CustomExceptionHandler not able to catch exceptions in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

In my spring boot application, I have created a custom exception handler using `@ControllerAdvice`, and a custom exception `ServerException`, when I throw the custom exception, it does not get caught by my customExcpetionHandler, though I am able to check whether actually the excpetion is thrown and it is getting thrown as shown by logs.

Below is the code for my ServerException:

```
public class ServerException extends Exception {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = <uid>;

public ServerException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

}
```

Below is my GlobalCustomExceptionHandler class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class GlobalCustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

@ExceptionHandler(ServerException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public ModelMap handleServerException(ServerException ex) {
    ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
    modelMap.addAttribute("status", "ERROR_400_Bad_Request");
    modelMap.addAttribute("error_message", ex.getMessage());
    return modelMap;
}

}
```

I am throwing the exception in one of the restcontroller as follows:

```
throw new ServerException("invalid server configs");
```

But I can only see the exception getting printed in log file, and not getting it as response mentioned in handleServerException() method of GlobalCustomExceptionHandler class.

What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

I have just reproduced Your copy-pasted piece of code with simple REST endpoint, and it works as expected:

```
@RestController
public class SystemController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/system")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getSystem() throws ServerException {
        if (true)
            throw new ServerException("Checking this out");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Calling `http://localhost:8080/system`

Results with:

```
{"status":"ERROR_400_Bad_Request","error_message":"Checking this out"}
```

I need bigger picture to help You. Paste controller that is throwing that as well as main application config class.

Comment: never mind, I have figured it out as the controller in the code was catching the exceptions and printing the stacktrace for the exception. That was the reason that it was printing it in the logs and GlobalExceptionHandler didn't pick it.